# How to match a string from array of strings using javascript and regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi below is an array of strings,

```
const arr = [
    "list-domain/1/",
    "list-domain/1/list/1",
    "some-group/2/",
    "some-group/2/list/2",
    "list/3/",
    "list/3/item/1"
];
```

I want to return true if the string matches `"list/1/"` or `"list-domain/2/list/2/"` or `"some-group/3/list/4"`; so basically should return true if string starts with `"list/1/"` or has some string in front and ends with "/list/1/"

note: here the number after slash can be any number.

so for the above array expected output is true.

```
 const arr1 = [
    "list-domain/1/",
    "list-domain/1/list/1",
    "some-group/2/",
    "some-group/2/list/2",
];
```

for arr1 expected output true

```
 const arr2 = [
    "list-domain/1/",
    "list-domain/1/list/1/item/2",
    "some-group/2/",
];
```

for arr2 expected output is false.

i have tried something like below,

```
const foundMatch = arr.some(a=> new RegExp(/(\/list\/[0-9]+)?\/$/g).test(a));
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: Remove the `?`. The constructor is useless, use a literal pattern.The parenthesis are useless too. If you want to allow `list` at the start of the string, change the first `\/` to `(?:\/|^)`

Comment: thanks so should it be arr.some(a => /(?:\/|^)list\/[0-9]+)?\/$/g.test(a));

Comment: you can use this website (https://rubular.com/) to test your regexes against samples and see what is wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match particular strings in an array using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985007/how-to-match-particular-strings-in-an-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to have?

```
arr.some(a=> new RegExp(/list\/[0-9](\/)?$/g).test(a));
```

Your above all cases fulfills by this regex. If not you can put other test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr.some(a=> new RegExp(/(^list\/\d\/)|(list\/\d\/$)/).test(a));
```

If that's what you mean by:

> If string starts with "**list/1/**" or has some string in front and ends with "**list/1/**".